# Unhashable type error

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

Trying to do this:

```
ls = np.empty
ls =getColA()
rs = np.empty
rs=getColG()
x = dict(itertools.izip(ls,rs))
```

and getting this error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

would appreciate if anyone could help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `dict` must have the key set as a hashable type.

You are trying to create a type using a non-hashable type (numpy.ndarray).

This is why you get this error.

In you case, you could do:

```
x = dict(itertools.izip(tuple(ls),rs))
```

Comment: What should i use instead? i have columns from xlsx files that i need to combine as tuples

Comment: @Hassaan You have to use an hashable type like a tuple, for instance `x = dict(itertools.izip(tuple(ls),rs))`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 2):

When you are using `itertools.izip(ls,rs)` the first column will be contain numpy arrays which are not hashable to stand as dictionary keys.

You have to convert them to a hashable iterable like `tuple` instead. Also if you want to concatenate two numpy arrays along their second axis it's better to use `np.column_stack()` instead of `itertools.izip()`.

Also It's not clear that what the `getColA` object is and what it's returning. Maybe you can modify that callable object in order to make a more proper result.

Comment: How do i render a numpy array hashable? Or what data structure should i use as a key?

Comment: @Hassaan *You have to convert them to a hashable iterable like tuple instead. Also if you want to concatenate two numpy arrays along their second axis it's better to use np.column_stack() instead of itertools.izip().*

Comment: sorry for being slow, i got you. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There several things that don't make sense

```
ls = np.empty
ls =getColA()
```

`np.empty` is a function.  You assign that to `ls`; then you assign the result of `getColA()` to `ls`.  That wipes out the first assignment.  Do you think the first assignment defines the `ls` variable as an array?  That's not how Python works.  Variables don't have a type.

```
x = dict(itertools.izip(ls,rs))
```

You didn't tell us what `getColA()` returns, but the error indicates that it is an array. 1d? 2d?

This sort of dictionary building works with 1d arrays (I'm using PY3)

```
In [497]: dict(itertools.zip_longest(np.arange(3),np.arange(10,13)))
Out[497]: {0: 10, 1: 11, 2: 12}
```

but not with 2d

```
In [498]: dict(itertools.zip_longest(np.arange(6).reshape(2,3),np.ones((2,3))))
...
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

That's because the `zip` on 2d returns the rows of the arrays, and the rows themselves are arrays:

```
In [499]: list(itertools.zip_longest(np.arange(6).reshape(2,3),np.ones((2,3))
     ...: ))
Out[499]: 
[(array([0, 1, 2]), array([ 1.,  1.,  1.])),
 (array([3, 4, 5]), array([ 1.,  1.,  1.]))]
```

Why do you want to use an array as dictionary key?

Comment: getColA() is returning an array of some data from cells of excel file. i wanted to combine two columns of different excel files so as to use them as dictionary.

Comment: and as you said, i am new to python and trying to get hold of the structure and syntax. Assigning np.empty was an attempt to define its type but was confused how variables work in python.

Comment: You need to give a concrete example, with real numbers and arrays.  What exactly is a dictionary key supposed to look like?